# How do i "skip" a row if there is a failure on a sql function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I want to create a stored procedure in sql server which will allow me to skip the row and move on to the next row when an error is encountered. For example, when i pass in an input of 'BOZ3C 51' it works, but fails with the error - 'Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.' when it encounters an input of 'C Z3C'

```
BEGIN TRY
select distinct LEFT(SUBSTRING(ticker,1,CHARINDEX(' ',ticker) -1),len(SUBSTRING(ticker,1,CHARINDEX(' ',ticker) -1))-3)as CLASS 
from SECURITY
SET @RETMSG = 'SUCCESS'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SET @RETMSG = 'SecClass ERRNUM: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ERROR_NUMBER()) + ' SecClass     ERRMSG: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE();
print @RETMSG
END CATCH;
```

How can i handle such situations? Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: You can use a `CASE` expression to (try to) detect problems before they occur, e.g. `case when CharIndex( ' ', ticker ) = 0 then 'n/a' else ... end`.  `CASE` does not reliably provide short circuit evaluation in the presence of aggregation functions.  See [CASE / COALESCE won't always evaluate in textual order](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/690017/case-coalesce-wont-always-evaluate-in-textual-order) and [Aggregates Don't Follow the Semantics Of CASE](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/691535/aggregates-dont-follow-the-semantics-of-case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to guarantee that you avoid the error in SQL Server is to use the `case` statement.  SQL Server reserves the right to rearrange operations . . . and this means that the calculation in the `SELECT` might happen before the filtering in the `WHERE`.

```
select distinct (case when len(SUBSTRING(tinker,1,CHARINDEX(' ',tinker) -1)) >= 3
                      then LEFT(SUBSTRING(ticker,1,CHARINDEX(' ',ticker) -1),len(SUBSTRING(ticker,1,CHARINDEX(' ',ticker) -1))-3)as CLASS 
                 end) -- if not appropriate format, then return `NULL`
from SECURITY;
```

`case` is in general guaranteed to evaluate the `when` clauses in order and before the `then` (there are exceptions involving aggregated functions, but they do not apply in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a where clause that filters out rows that will fail.

```
where len(SUBSTRING(tinker,1,CHARINDEX(' ',tinker) -1)) - 3 >= 0
```

The best solution would to make everything more programtic.  The issue is that you are checking how many characters are before a space, then subtracting 3. If you can calculate a number instead of substracting 3 every time and avoid going below 0, that would solve the errors.